# Package and use embedded database (H2.db file) inside a Jar?

Tags: java, database, jar, packaging, h2

I'm using H2 embedded database for my application. I would like to contain everything the application needs in it's own Jar, **including it's database** if possible. My app does not need to create temp files or anything, so basically the user just runs the Jar.

**Is it possible to embed a database inside a Jar, and be able to `INSERT` new records as well as just `SELECT` out?**

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm not looking to embed the H2 driver jar inside my distributable jar, I'm looking to embed the h2 database file (`someDatabase.h2.db` file) inside a Jar and still be able to write/read from that database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you wish to embed the `myDatabase.h2.db` file inside the `.jar`, you can do so, but you'll have read-only access to the database. As `.jar` files are read-only, you can't modify them and therefore can't execute `INSERT`, `DELETE` or any DDL command.

That being said, below is an explanation on how to embed it read-only.

According to [H2's documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html#connect):

The JDBC URL `"jdbc:h2:~/myDatabase"` tells the H2 Engine to look for a database file named `myDatabase.h2.db` in the **home directory** of the current user.

The JDBC URL `"jdbc:h2:file:/myDatabase"` tells the H2 Engine to look for a database file named `myDatabase.h2.db` in the **current directory** (where the java program was executed).

If you embed the `h2.db` file inside a `.jar`, it is not accessible in a plain way. It is only accessible as a file inside a zip file.

In order to make H2 uset it, you have to use a zip as URL:

```
jdbc:h2:zip:~/data.zip!/test
```

See more in "[Read Only Databases in Zip or Jar File](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#database_in_zip)".

When you embed the file as a resource in the jar, you may get it's relative url. Using...

`MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("myDatabase.h2.db")`

...you'll get something like:

`jar:file:/C:/folder1/folder2/myJar.jar!/myDatabase.h2.db`

You can then manipulate it as a String and pass as JDBC URL connection to H2.

Comment: see my Edit above. More looking to embed the database file itself (ie. someDatabase.h2.db file" inside my Jar, not the driver jar.

Comment: One thing I can already tell you: even if you could embedd the h2.db file inside the .jar, you wouldnt be able to do inserts, as the jar file is read-only...

Comment: I was afraid of that... even if the jar isn't compressed (jars are just zip's really), I wasn't sure if I could r/w to it...

Comment: I guess people's way around this is to just create a new database and import a schema on first program run... and stash it in a hidden directory under user's home directory... so in `%userprofile%/AppData/.someProgramdb/someDatabase.h2.db` or `~/.someProgram/db/someDatabase.h2.db`

Comment: Exactly. This is very common using `.properties` files. They use the read-only jar-embedded file until the user decides to make a change. When that happens, they create a file in a folder as you mentioned. (Or in the current jar's folder or subfolder.)

Comment: There you go. As it turns out, you **do** can use it as read-only. Check out the updated answer. Tell me if you need more code example.

Comment: Great answer and follow-up. Thanks a lot!

Comment: getResourceAsStream(...) only gives you the InputStream (and not an URL), you probably mean getResource(...)