# How can I connect to read only H2 database file which is inside runnable jar?

Tags: java, javafx, jar, zip, h2

I've requirement to create database once with create/insert statements and then make it available **inside javafx runnable jar** with **read only** DB access.

I just gone through H2 database document many time and tried to achieve this using `H2 Driver version 1.4.196 and 1.4.192` but I think I'm missing something.

**I can connect without including it into runnable jar and read only things works as well. But I need to access it from jar itself to prevent DB access from outsiders.**

Can I've connection string or logic to connect read only DB file from jar itself ?

Ofcourse I need more clear practical example from [this](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_in_zip), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15975509/3510195) and [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6507639/3510195)

I've implemented zipping logic as [this](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/test/org/h2/samples/ReadOnlyDatabaseInZip.java) and it works fine from given path.

But when I've added zip file in runnable jar and accessing it through following code:

`DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:split:zip:./test.zip!/test");`

Then it throws exception with:

`Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\jar\res\buzdirectory.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)"; "listFiles zip:./jar/res/buzdirectory.zip!/" [90031-196]`

If I put fully qualified path then it works well:

`DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:split:zip:C:\\CoreJava\\src\\main\\java\\res\\test.zip!/test");`

What I'm missing here to access it from jar file.

Comment: Where's the ZIP file stored?  Looks like you're referencing a non-existent file

Comment: Actually zip file path is perfect and exist but I think I'd messed up with file creation. Can I have steps to create the same ?

Comment: And the zip file contains the database?  Seems like you're putting the horse before the cart (but I might be misunderstanding where you're up to). Obviously, you need to have created the database, populated it's data before zipping it

Comment: Yes it contains database file named test.mv.db created by netbeans connection service and ran create/insert statements before zipping it by 7z.

Comment: Hmmm, does H2 support 7z?  Have your tried a more traditional ZIP archiver or even jar (which just uses ZIP)?

Comment: If your database file in your resources, try replace ~ by .

Comment: `~` sign is for User's default directory see this: http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#console_settings

Answer (score 0):

I *think* we cannot open the database file directly from the runnable JAR file. To access it should be a "real" file, so we will need to extract it from the JAR and then open that copy.

For example, to extract the database from the JAR into a temporary file:

```
File dbFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".zip");
dbFile.deleteOnExit();

java.nio.file.Files.copy(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/db/temp.zip"), 
        dbFile.toPath(), java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

StringBuffer connStr = new StringBuffer("jdbc:h2:file:split:zip:")
        .append(dbFile.getAbsolutePath()).append("!/temp");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr.toString());
conn.close();
System.out.println("closed");
```

By the way this is not preferable approach yet all. But we can use this kind of approach in some special cases.